# Is it possible to capture the XMLHttpRequest error response I can see in the console?

Tags: javascript, iframe, xmlhttprequest

Basically, I want to capture, and then parse, the XMLHttpRequest response, from a iframe.

Can i get this:

### [XHTTP REQUEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcsmU.png)

As a string in javascript

EDIT: 
I don't know why this is being down-voted.

This is not the same as asking for the response from a ajax request.
There is no code, or anything to show.

I have an iframe which is trying to request "http://website.com/page.php"

It fails (as i expect), but i want to capture the SPECIFIC message which is being logged in the console.

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: There is no code. - <iframe src="website.com/iframe.php"></iframe>

Comment: both are from the same domain? your page and the Iframe?

Comment: ~Both are not on the same domin. - this is what causes the error. I am expecting the error. It is the error response i am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Error messages XHR reports to the console are typically network failures and security violations.

Exposing the details of a security violation to the site which triggered it could leak confidential information.

Comment: I see, Admittedly, that makes sense.